# pyodbc can read the column names from a table, but a query on the table raises a does not exist error

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc, amazon-athena

I'm trying to query a table an AWS athena via pyodbc. I have succesfully created a connection and can even read the column names via pyodbc, but when i try and query the table, it apparently does not exist.

```
import pyodbc

import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=databaseDSN;UID=user;PWD=password')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for row in cursor.tables():
     print(row.table_name)
```

This gives a list of the table names in my database.

```
for row in cursor.columns(table='tablename'):
     print(row.column_name)
```

This gives me the correct column names in my table.

```
sql = "Select * From tablename"
data = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
```

This throws an error

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'Select * From tablename': ('42000', '[42000] [Simba][Athena] (1040) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Error Message: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:15: Table awsdatacatalog.default.tablename does not exist
```

Comment: I would suggest using boto3 the following github repo has all the code you need  https://github.com/raoofnaushad/AWSathena_s3_python or the long article https://medium.com/dataseries/automating-athena-queries-from-s3-with-python-and-save-it-as-csv-8917258b1045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem, my table was within a schema.

I fixed it with:

```
sql = "Select * From schema.tablename"
data = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
```

Comment: Table awsdatacatalog.default.tablename does not exist